# How to print photo in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, airprint

I need to print photo using AirPrinter and already coded but I have one problem with photo size.
After print photo, I can see that output photo size is too large - correctly I want to print A6(4*6 inch) photo.

I use Canon MG3260 as Air Printer.

Please help me if what I can solve this problem.

- Screenshot
  https://www.dropbox.com/s/1f6wa0waao56zqk/IMG_0532.jpg
- Code

  ```
  -(void)printPhotoWithImage:(UIImage *)image {

  NSData *myData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.f); UIPrintInteractionController *pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];

  if (pic && [UIPrintInteractionController canPrintData:myData]) {

  pic.delegate = self;
  UIPrintInfo *pinfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
  pinfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputPhoto;
  pinfo.jobName = @"My Photo";
  pinfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;

  pic.printInfo = pinfo;
  pic.showsPageRange = YES;
  pic.printingItem = myData;

  pic.printFormatter = format;
  [format release];

  void(^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) = ^(UIPrintInteractionController *print, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {

  [self resignFirstResponder];

  if (!completed && error) {
      NSLog(@"--- print error! ---");
  }

  };

     [pic presentFromRect:CGRectMake((self.view.bounds.size.width - 64) + 27, (self.view.bounds.size.height - 16) + 55, 0, 0) inView:self.view animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
  ```

  }

  ```
   - (UIPrintPaper *)printInteractionController:(UIPrintInteractionController *)printInteractionController choosePaper:(NSArray *)paperList {

   CGSize pageSize = CGSizeMake(6 * 72, 4 * 72); return [UIPrintPaper bestPaperForPageSize:pageSize withPapersFromArray:paperList];

  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Scale the image first and then use it to print

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```